# How to cancle process in Orange Canvas?

Tags: python, process, orange

Hey I started to use the graphical orange canvas toolbox for data mining. Connecting nodes on the workspace can cause the execution of the associated tasks. I know that these automatic apply can be disabled, but in the case I missed that and accidently start a realy heavy process like outliner detection on a big dataset is there a way to stop the current pipeline task without killing the hole system process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such stopping functionality in Orange yet.

The developers of Orange are working towards making widgets compute in threads, which can let us control stopping. The Test & Learn widget, for example, already works in a separate thread. There, if the user changes options while widget is already working, it stops the current computation and starts a new one. But even there, there is no GUI option to just stop the computation.

Comment: Ok, I already realized, that the score widgets don't block the hole program all the time, this seems to be the reason. Than I'm looking forward and hope the software will keep raising. Even if the possibility to do complex algorithms like hyperopt etc. is limited, it offers a nice workflow for basic tasks and awesome visualizations.